# My df.drop_duplicates() results are not matching excel's remove duplicate, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've just starting learning python and am trying to remove rows that are deemed as duplicates based on 2 columns but can't seem to match the results from Excel.

To illustrate I've copied the below from panda's doc as it's similar to what I want to do,

```
df
    brand style  rating
0  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
1  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
3  Indomie  pack    15.0
4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['brand', 'style'], keep='last')
    brand style  rating
1  Yum Yum   cup     4.0
2  Indomie   cup     3.5
4  Indomie  pack     5.0
```

Below is what I've tried

```
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv", dtype=str)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = ["NAME", "EMAIL"],  keep = "first")
```

This gives me 83563 rows x 17 columns.

But if I were to use excel's remove duplicates button to remove duplicates and tick the boxes "NAME" and "EMAIL", I am left with 80293 rows instead, a difference of around 3k rows.

Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding something?

Comment: What happen with:  df[['brand', 'style']].drop_duplicates(keep='last').
Instead of subset?

Comment: Hi Luis Alejandro Vargas Ramos, 
I've tried using df[['NAME', 'EMAIL']].drop_duplicates(keep='last') as suggested and it shows 83563 rows too.

Comment: What's the shape there? How many rows?

Comment: you're calling the function correctly, or at least, that is a valid way to call the function. but we can't help you debug vs. an excel workflow we can't see. can you identify the ones that *are* different between pandas and excel, and see if you can identify the differences? just a guess - it's possible you're encountering encoding issues

Comment: Maybe excel is removing duplicates in the whole document and this code is just looking inside the subset.

Comment: @YiJie, do you know have null values in either of `Name` or `Email` columns?

Comment: @ Michael Delgado, I've tried your suggestion of identifying them and found the issue. 

By using the remove duplicate tool in Excel, Excel will proceed to remove all duplicates based on the columns selected REGARDLESS of if values are in upper or lower case, meaning that in Excel's eyes, abc@gmail.com and ABC@GMAIL.COM are treated as the same value.

In pandas/python however, abc@gmail.com and ABC@GMAIL.COM are treated as 2 different values and are not considered as duplicates, which resulted in a different output. 

Thank you everyone for the suggestions! I feel so dumb now :/

Comment: You can answer your own question for future people having same issue. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if your values are all in upper/lower case if you faced this too.

By using the remove duplicate tool in Excel, Excel will proceed to remove all duplicates based on the columns selected REGARDLESS of if values are in upper or lower case, meaning that in Excel's eyes, abc@gmail.com and ABC@GMAIL.COM are treated as the same value.

In pandas/python however, abc@gmail.com and ABC@GMAIL.COM are treated as 2 different values and are not considered as duplicates, which resulted in a different output.